# Can't execute find with os.system

Tags: python-3.x, bash, shell, os.system

I am trying to run the following command via my python script, to unzip a bunch of `csv.gz` files

```
os.system("find /upload/ -name '*.csv.gz' -print -exec gzip -d {} \") <- Syntax error : EOL while scanning string literal.

#When I try to escape it

os.system("find /upload/ -name '*.csv.gz' -print -exec gzip -d {} \\") <- find: missing parameter for « -exec »
```

How can I execute `find /upload/ -name '*.csv.gz' -print -exec gzip -d {} \` via os.system?

Is there any alternative to `os.system("find /upload/ -name '*.csv.gz' -print0 |  xargs -0 -n1 gzip -d")` I could use?

Answer (score 1):

Not using a shell at all is actually a simplification here, as long as you understand what you are doing.  You have to add the missing semicolon as already mentioned in the other answer.

```py
import subprocess

subprocess.run([
    'find', '/upload/', '-name', '*.csv.gz', '-print',
    '-exec', 'gzip', '-d', '{}', ';'], check=True)
```

Maybe see also [Running Bash commands in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python/51950538#51950538)

Answer (score 0):

You need an (escaped) semicolon:

`os.system("find /upload/ -name '*.csv.gz' -print -exec gzip -d {} \\;")`